# Hadoop Datanode starts on wrong interface

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, cloudera, network-interface

We used 2 interfaces for our hadoop cluster. Private eth-1 and public. It looks like when hadoop datanode starts, it picks public IP address instead of private. When I look at hadoop-cmf-hdfs-DATANODE-hostname.log.out, it shows up

```
STARTUP_MSG: Starting DataNode
STARTUP_MSG:   host = hostname.public.net/208.x.x.x
```

where instead it should say

```
STARTUP_MSG: Starting DataNode
STARTUP_MSG:   host = hostname-eth1.private.net/192.168.x.x
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a setting in hdfs-site.xml, which can control the interface, that is used by the Data Node as its IP address.

**dfs.datanode.dns.interface    =   The name of the Network Interface from which a data node should report its IP address.**

This is set to "default". If you want to use eth1, then set this property in hdfs-site.xml as:

```
<property>
    <name>dfs.datanode.dns.interface</name>
    <value>eth1</value>
  </property>
```

To quote from "Hadoop The Definitive Guide" book:

`There is also a setting for controlling which network interfaces the datanodes use as their IP addresses (for HTTP and RPC servers). The relevant property is
dfs.datanode.dns.interface, which is set to default to use the default network
interface. You can set this explicitly to report the address of a particular interface (eth0, for example).`

Comment: Thank you but that line uses reverse dns query to get hostname binded to IP address on that eth1 interface. Unfortunately I dont have reverse dns in place. Is there somewhere that I can insert full qualified hostname-eth1 so it doesn't look for reverse dns ?

Comment: There is one more setting: "dfs.namenode.datanode.registration.ip-hostname-check". See the description of this setting here: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/hdfs-default.xml

Comment: No luck. On /var/logs/hadoop-hdfs 
It is binding wrong hostname
`org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BlockScanner: Initialized block scanner with targetBytesPerSec 1048576
2015-10-20 18:47:08,408 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: File descriptor passing is enabled.
2015-10-20 18:47:08,409 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Configured hostname is hostname.public.net`
last line must be `org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Configured hostname is hostname-eth1.private.net`

Comment: I checked the Hadoop code. While getting the host name, it calls function DNS.getDefaultHost(), which takes 2 parameters: interface and nameserver. For setting the nameserver, you need to set one more parameter: "dfs.datanode.dns.nameserver". This can be left to "default" value also.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this property as quoted from [apache web site](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsMultihoming.html#DataNodes_use_HostNames_when_connecting_to_other_DataNodes)? (***Whether datanodes should use datanode hostnames when connecting to other datanodes for data transfer.***)

```
<property>
  <name>dfs.datanode.use.datanode.hostname</name>
  <value>true</value>
  <description>Whether datanodes should use datanode hostnames when
    connecting to other datanodes for data transfer.
  </description>
</property>
```

Check for other datanode properties like `dfs.datanode.address` as per [hdfs properties](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/hdfs-default.xml) and you can find a solution

One more thing: Check your IP/Domain name mapping in hosts file.